# Wrong date with javascript function toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, string, date, locale

I use the javascript function of the Date class toLocaleDateString() in a project to get the proper formatting according to the user's locale, so simple. However, the day of the month is not always right (It is somethimes one day less than expected). I cannot seem to understand why this happens.

I built a jsfiddle to show the problem. It occurs with the month of october. The date should be 3 like in all the other months but somehow it's 2.

https://jsfiddle.net/vincepunkrock/nh1u3ord/

Here is the important part of code and the result (My locale is 'de'):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    var d = new Date(1993,i,3);
    var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += n + "<br>";
}

3.1.1993
3.2.1993
3.3.1993
3.4.1993
3.5.1993
3.6.1993
3.7.1993
3.8.1993
3.9.1993
2.10.1993
3.11.1993
3.12.1993
```

Do you guys have an idea about what's happening here and what can I do to solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When did "summer time" (or "daylight savings time") end in 1993 in your locale?

Comment: It was on sept. 26th. Indeed, when I set the date to the 27th, I get the 26th  for the months of september and october. You were on the right track!

Comment: "*…to get the proper formatting according to the user's locale…*". There's no guarantee that will happen, since *toLocaleDateString* is entirely implementation dependent and some implementations seem to ignore user settings entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Pointy nailed it with his comment. toLocalDateString is definitely factoring in DST with a presumed hour of 00:00:0000 since it's not being specified so the "fall back" hour goes into the prior day. I'm not sure what your locale is to have that only happen in one month but I'm not a pro on time zones. The script works perfectly for me.

Update: set the "time" in your new date to the middle of the day if this isn't the behavior you want.. then the Daylight savings time adjustment won't kick back and forth into different dates..

```
var d = new Date(1993,i,3, 12,30,30,30);
```

Comment: How the change to DST on the exact moment of change is handled varies between implementations. It should be sufficient to set the hours to any time one or more hours after midnight since nowhere has a change of more than an hour (some have less), so `new Date(1993,i,3,1)` should be sufficient. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

On Firefox (60) this doesn't show up when initializing the date from numbers (my timezone is GMT-3: observe how the `Date` initializer adds 3 hours automatically):

```
>> var d;
>> d = new Date(2019,10,17);
Date 2019-11-17T03:00:00.000Z
>> console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('de'))
17.11.2019
```

However, when initializing it from a string, problems show up:

```
>> d = new Date("2019-10-17");
Date 2019-10-17T00:00:00.000Z
>> console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('de'))
16.11.2019
```

What I found out could solve the problem was manually specifying the timezone as UTC:

```
>> console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('de', {timeZone: "UTC"}))
17.10.2019
```

Comment: The {timeZone: "UTC"} solution is more elegant and works on Chrome!

Comment: When I do this, I lose my 'options' formatting, as date.toLocaleDateString takes only 2 arguments, and the first one has to be the locale (or undefined).  The day is then correct, however.  Using Nuxt, setting the time zone in db.js to 'utc' makes no difference..  What fixed it for me (in MN, DST) was adding an hour argument of 12 to the Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd, hr).  Adding 3 didn't do it; 12 did.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with french Language first. It seems the language settings of your browser affects the results in a strange manner.
Check your browser language settings.

Comment: The use of "Locale" in the method name is a misnomer. The *toLocaleString* methods are entirely implementation dependent and do not take "locale" into consideration, otherwise they would change formatting of the string based on the geographic location of the device, not user settings (which is what they actually seem to do, if they use anything at all).